# Have apps that "support Chromecast", want to send to TV using MiraCast

Tags: chromecast, miracast

Situation:

- I have an app on my phone that says it supports "Chromecast" (mechanism not specified).
- I have an TV (Sharp) that supports MiraCast (protocol).

Is there any way to provide the "Chromecast" API (whatever it's actually called) endpoint to a local app and use MiraCast to send to the TV?

I am *not* asking:

- how to turn on screen mirroring [I can, but it works poorly]
- how to obtain or use a Chromecast device [I know Google wants to sell them]
- the difference between the two? [I have read around a bit]

I have read through a number of questions about MiraCast and Chromecast, but most seem to be "what's the difference?" and the few asking for "how to...?" seem to be "how do I re-enable screen-mirroring support in Android?" which isn't the issue, since there *are* multiple apps that use MiraCast protocol to connect to TVs and play video.

I need to know, specifically, whether there is a pre-existing app that can provide a "Chromecast"-like interface at the client side, and use the "MiraCast" protocol to connect to the TV.

If not, is it possible for me to write one, or is there something about the 'cast services that's restricted so it can't be provided by a non-Google-sourced app? **Not asking *how* to write one, I'm hoping I don't need to try.**

As per @MorrisonChang's comment, we actually have three devices we'd like to be able to use for this, all Huawei: an HONOR 20 Lite, a P Smart (not the 2019 update), and an older P9 Lite which has a dying battery but works fine plugged in. Android version is Pie on the HONOR; I believe the P Smart shipped with Oreo but has since had a Pie update available (not my device, so not sure if it has been updated or not).

Comment: You don't mention which phone you have. Related: [Steps to programmatically cast from android to miracast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33828968/295004) Note that programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @MorrisonChang it isn't specifically a programming question, I'm hoping there's an app I've failed to find or that I've overlooked a feature / setting somewhere. I'm fairly sure that SO would have deemed this as off-topic there.

Comment: `I can, but it works poorly` you still haven't mentioned what device(s) & OS version. Chromecast != Miracast so anyone using the Chromecast SDK isn't supporting Miracast directly. I suspect that to use Miracast (official vs OEM display SDK) would require a pairing first at the OS level then the app would then see the secondary display.